# Maximize area of a triangle given n points

Tags: c, geometry, area, maximize

The code runs perfectly when I arbitrarily pass arguments to the area function. But gives me a segmentation fault when I try to run the loops. Given n<100

Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double area(int x,int y,int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
{       //Heron's formula
    double a,b,c,s;
    double abc;
    a=sqrt(((x-x1)*(x-x1))+((y-y1)*(y-y1)));
    b=sqrt(((x-x2)*(x-x2))+((y-y2)*(y-y2)));
    c=sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
    s=(a+b+c)/2;
    abc=sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
    return(abc);
}
int main(void)
{   

    int n,i,j,k;
    double max=0,z=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int x[100]={},y[100]={};
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&x[i],&y[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            for(k=j+1;k<n;j++)
            {
                z=area(x[i],y[i],x[j],y[j],x[k],y[k]);
                printf("%lf\n",z);
                if(z>max)
                {
                    max=z;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("\n%lfoi\n",area(0,0,1,0,1,2));
    printf("%lf",max*2);

}
```

Comment: You're most likely going out of bounds somewhere. Try to isolate the problem. Your code is very difficult to read as is.

Comment: Next time you post, remember to check over your code formatting. Overall, it wasn't too bad, and I fixed it for you, just a friendly reminder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inner loop is incrementing `j`, it should probably increment `k`:

```
for(k=j+1;k<n;j++)
              ^
             oops!
```

Comment: Same for you too.
Imma go cover my face with a paperbag or something.

Answer (score 3):

there is an error index in inner loop: should be

```
for(k=j+1;k<n;k++)
```

instead of

```
for(k=j+1;k<n;j++)
```

Comment: I can't believe i made that error. 
I really apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @OleGooner Don't think of it that way, we are here to help you, it was a fun exercise

Comment: Took me a minute to see the difference: `k++` instead of `j++`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(k=j+1;k<n;j++)
```

I think you meant to increment k in this loop, not j.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase "k" not "j"

```
 for(k=j+1;k<n;k++)
        { }
```